# Love2d canvas, blury character sprite

Tags: canvas, lua, 2d, game-engine, love2d

I developed a 2d engine using love2d (lua), drawing sprites wasn't a problem. Due to messy code, I had to recode everything.

I have now the same engine with a cleaner code.
I wasnt drawing in a canvas and had performance problem.

Now everything is fine, displayed in my canvas.But only my charset is blury. I did not resized / rescaled everything so I dont understand why it does happen.

I cant show a minimal code but at the end of the day, despite all game objects im just drawing with : love.graphics.draw( image, quad, x, y )

[it is blury :/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQSJe.png)

Edit : it start not blurry, it happens when I start to move my character(and then never goes away).
But i just change x and y when I does that...

Edit2 : the more i move my character the less it is blury (i mean it stops when i move a bit my character.
My animation timer arent refreshed when there is only one frame ( like idle animations ). But i dont know how it could be related... there is no redraw when i animate, i just change the frame index.. Im confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the FilterMode? After creating your image or canvas you should set the FilterMode to "Nearest", "Nearest" for pixelized scaling:

```
local image = love.graphics.newImage("ball.png")
image:setFilterMode("nearest", "nearest")
```

http://love2d.org/wiki/FilterMode

Comment: There was nooo way i found that magically, out of nowhere on google, i love you bro. You just made my day